# What's the equivalent of FMS for iphone?

Tags: iphone, flash, flash-media-server

Since iphone doesn't support flash at all.

Is it **Darwin streaming server** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use what Apple refers to as [HTTP Live Streaming](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).  Follow that link to Apple's Overview documentation.  That should give you enough to start with, as well as links to more detailed documentation.

In particular, take note of the [Requirements for Apps](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-DontLinkElementID_20) section. Here Apple lays out the required use of HTTP Live Streaming for iOS apps that will be delivering video over the cellular network.

Answer (score 1):

You can stream video (H.264) on iphone with [Wowza Media Server 2](http://www.wowzamedia.com/)